# whtats equivalent of db.products.findOne().product in pymongo

Tags: mongodb

in mongodb command i have this code:

`db.products.findOne().product`

now i wanna use this in pymongo (as you know via python)

is there any code similar in pymongo module ?

Comment: The `find_one` method returns a document or `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo documentation is here: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

The equivalent in pymongo is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

product = db.product.find_one().get('product') 
print(product)
```